# How can I get the value of the selected ChoiceType in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

With Symfony 3.3, I already try something like this, but no response:

```
<tr>
    {% for choice in form.vars.value.clients %}
        <td>{{ choice.value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Here is my formType:

```
$builder->add('name')
        ->add('contact')
        ->add('idprofession')
        ->add('idcard');
```

I have changed nothing because for the foreign key it is by default a choice, I want to recover the value of id profession

Comment: try do use {{ dump(choice) }} and check whether your getting any value in the variable or its empty.

Comment: {{ dump(choice) }} return nothing

Comment: Then I think you have not got the proper values. Can you please try dumping the value in controller for testing purpose like print_r(from); And if possible can you paste the same dump in the above question. So that we will get to know whats the output

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `form.clients.vars.value` ?

as this should give you the value that is selected

Comment: @Mii are you sure that you have selected anything? can you give us your form type code

Comment: this is an forgein key of my entity and I want to get the value of the forgein key

Comment: @Mii but do you have pre-selected anything in your form, can you post your form type, can't help you much without form, also check the answer Matteo posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectedchoice` Twig test:

```
<option {% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %} ...>
```

As described [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-twig-selectedchoice).

Hope this help